# JUnit4 BeforeClass tag not calling method

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit

I am currently having an issue setting up JUnit tests. I have a method in my test class to initialize objects that the tests will use, but for some reason the method is not being called.

I am using junit 4.13.1 with jdk1.8

My POM file dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

My Test class:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 *
 * @author mohdm
 */
public class StudentTest {
    private Student s1, s2;
    private Module m1, m2;
    private Course c1, c2;
    
    @BeforeClass
    public void setup(){
        s1 = new Student("Mohamed Moustafa", 32, new DateTime("1988-11-21"), 1728);
        s2 = new Student("Mohamed Moustafa", 34, new DateTime("1986-11-01"), 1708);
        
        m1 = new Module("Programming", "CT101");
        m2 = new Module("Paradigms", "CT201");
        
        c1 = new Course("CS&IT", new DateTime("2020-08-01"), new DateTime("2021-05-25"));
        c2 = new Course("ECE", new DateTime("2020-08-01"), new DateTime("2021-05-25"));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testSetup(){
        assertNotNull(s1);
    }
}
```

Yet I am getting this in maven surefire report:

> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Test set: StudentTest
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002
>
> sec <<< FAILURE! StudentTest.testSetup()  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<<
>
> FAILURE! java.lang.AssertionError     at
>
> org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:87)     at
>
> org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:42)   at
>
> org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:713)   at
>
> org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:723)   at
>
> StudentTest.testSetup(StudentTest.java:32)

Meaning that the objects arent being initialized and that the setup method isnt being called. I am new to JUnit, but the examples I saw online either use Before or BeforeClass tags for similar methods, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need these methods  to be static, so they'll be executed before running the tests of the class.

https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/122

```
 @BeforeClass
 public static  void setup(){
    s1 = new Student("Mohamed Moustafa", 32, new DateTime("1988-11-21"), 1728);
    s2 = new Student("Mohamed Moustafa", 34, new DateTime("1986-11-01"), 1708);
    
    m1 = new Module("Programming", "CT101");
    m2 = new Module("Paradigms", "CT201");
    
    c1 = new Course("CS&IT", new DateTime("2020-08-01"), new DateTime("2021-05-25"));
    c2 = new Course("ECE", new DateTime("2020-08-01"), new DateTime("2021-05-25"));
}
```

Comment: What about using @Before? They say it is only needed for BeforeClass, but I am getting the exact same issue if I use @Before.

Comment: @Before should work as that method gets executed before each test call

Comment: Yes, it should, but it doesnt.